# My application cannot see my table (list is returned empty) in Kotlin and Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have quiz application and I have created default 12 records for that app using sqlite. I can see my table when I execute Select query in Sqlite , but in my android app , list is coming empty. There is no problem in accessing database , code is correct since I can see my table . But problem is I can not access records. Viewmodel returns empty list. Using Inspector I can see that table exists but records are not as it is shown below in picture : [image]

But when I check my table from sqlite , I can see there is no any problem with records , they are inserted correctly . Here is query result in sqlite : [image]

Code :

```
@Dao
interface QuizDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE difficulty = :selectedDifficulty")
    fun loadQuiz(selectedDifficulty : String) : List<Quiz>
}
```

Database :

```
@Database(entities = [Quiz::class] , version = 1)
abstract class QuizDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun getQuizDao() : QuizDao
}
```

Repo :

```
class QuizRepository(var qdao: QuizDao) {
     fun loadQuestions(difficulty: String): List<Quiz> = qdao.loadQuiz(difficulty)
}
```

Viewmodel :

```
@HiltViewModel
class GameViewModel @Inject constructor(var quizRepository: QuizRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val quizList = MutableLiveData<List<Quiz>>()


    init {
        loadAllQuestion()
    }

    private fun loadAllQuestion(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            quizList.value = quizRepository.loadQuestions("Easy")
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment :

```
  viewModel.quizList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                if (it.isNotEmpty()){
                selectedQuestions = it.shuffled().take(10)
                displayCurrentQuestion()}
                else{
                    Log.e("tag","Empty")
                }
            }
```

I get tag empty .

Comment: Well you obviously opened a different file in the second screenshot.

Comment: Which file did you use in the second screenshot (SQLite Viewer)?

Comment: it is same file which I used in my project.

Comment: Yes but where does it come from. Did you pull it using ADB?